# Binary Checker In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

how would I check if a number is considered Binary or not. I'll put my code in here, but regardless of what number came up, it would show up as False.

```py
def AmIBinary(aString):
    aString = str(aString)
    if aString.isalpha():
        return False
    elif aString.isdigit():
        for aString in [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: After confirming the string is full of digits, you probably intended to loop through the string and check its characters one by one. But you don't have a loop. What you have is a condition check that the FULL string is any digit except 0 or 1. Which is always False for a string.

Comment: What is your understanding of `binary`?

Comment: Bigger picture, pretty much all numbers in computers are represented by binary numbers, even the Decimal types are built from smaller binary numbers. If you wanted to see if the *decimal representation* in strings and printing only has 1s and 0s, this code would do it.

Comment: `return not (set(str(a_string)) - set('01')`)

Comment: @BatWannaBe Look at the OP's list of digits: every decimal digit except 0 and 1. Don't you think it's fairly obvious what OP meant by *binary*, even if was badly expressed?

Comment: @BoarGules I'm not jumping to that conclusion quite yet, it's possible OP would prefer a way to represent any number in binary over whether a decimal only has 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 1):

The following line is incorrect:

```
for aString in [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
```

This line of code returns False for every element in the list.

Instead, you should iterate through that list and check if that digit is inside the string:

```
def AmIBinary(aString):
    aString = str(aString)
    if aString.isalpha():
        return False
    elif aString.isdigit():
        for i in [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
          if str(i) in aString:
            return False
        else:
            return True

print(AmIBinary("010"))

print(AmIBinary("010")) #True
print(AmIBinary("0210"))#False
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check whether the input contains only 1s and 0s. The solution iterates the string just once.

```py
def AmIBinary(aString):
    aString = str(aString)
    if aString.isalpha():
        return False
    elif aString.isdigit():
        for item in aString:
            if item != '0' or item!= '1':
              return False
        return True
```